# Why is my macro saving as .xls when I specify .xlsx?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a macro that opens a file, performs some formatting on the file, and then saves it as a new file.  I have set as my file type .xlsx, and the file that I open is stored as .xlsx, yet when I save, it wants to save it as .xls, and then it won't open when I don't save it as .xls.  What is wrong with my code?

I got the save as code from another website, so that could be part of the issue.

```
Sub Main()
'
'// non-related code above...

    wBook.SaveAs Filename:=NewFile, _
        FileFormat:=xlNormal, _
        Password:="", _
        WriteResPassword:="", _
        ReadOnlyRecommended:=False, _
        CreateBackup:=False

    Set ActBook = wBook
    Workbooks.Open CurrentFile
    ActBook.Close
End If

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try changing `SaveAs.FileFormat` to `xlOpenXMLWorkbook`

```
wBook.SaveAs Filename:=NewFile, _
    FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, ...
```

You can get more info on the `Workbook.SaveAs` method [here (MSDN link)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.workbook.saveas.aspx), and the xlFileFormat enumerations [here (MSDN link)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.xlfileformat.aspx).

Comment: This worked, but I don't understand exactly why.  I leafed through those links that you put in there (first place I go with questions), and wasn't finding what I needed.

Comment: Check out [Ron de Bruin's writeup](http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s5/win001.htm) on this subject. It might help your understanding.